# First return map in complex 2DOF Hamiltonian systems

Tags: complex-manifolds, hamiltonian-mechanics

The standard way to construct the first return map around a periodic orbit in real 2DOF Hamiltonian systems is the following:

1. We choose a periodic orbit and a point on it.
2. We restrict the system on the hypersurface $\{H=c\}$
3. We fix a plane that passes through the point we have chosen and which is transversal to the periodic orbit.
4. We define the map on any point of the plane by following the evolution of the point until it hits the plane again.

Assume now that the system we started with is real analytic.

Let's denote this process by writing $P:\text{rHamSys} \to \text{rAPM}$.

Since the Hamiltonian system is real analytic, then the map we get is also real analytic (defined in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$), so we can complexify it trivially so it is defined in a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Let's denote this by $C:\text{rAPM}\to\text{cAPM}$.

Of course we can complexify the system before we construct the first return map, $C:\text{rHamSys}\to\text{cHamSys}$. So to my question, how can we define $F$ so the following diagram is commutative?

$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{rHamSys} & \ra{C} & \text{cHamSys} \\
\da{P} & & \da{F} \\
\text{rAPM} & \ra{c} & \text{cAPM} \\
\end{array}$

I tried to do the same but here's the problem:

1. The first step works exactly the same.
2. We can restrict the system on the hypersurface $\{H=c\}$ and this drops the dimension from $4$ complex to $3$ complex.
3. It becomes a bit tricky to fix a transversal, but this can be done.
4. The problem appears here. The plane does not separate the space in $\mathbb{C}^3$ so we cannot be sure that the trajectory of a given point will return to the plane at any point in the future.

Is there another way to do this? Is this something known?

(I'm not sure what are the appropriate tags for this question.)